# Gatling: requests are not displayed in html reports

Tags: java, scala, jar, gatling

please consider the scenario...

I am creating script of online file viewer(advance). This mode of viewer uses the jar files of java while viewing. 
There are various calls which are not shown in html reports.

```
.exec(http("request_42")
    .get(uri8 + "/url/url/trident.jar")
    .headers(headers_42)
    .check(status.is(304)))
.exec(http("request_43")
    .get(uri8 + "/url/url/substance.jar")
    .headers(headers_42)
    .check(status.is(304)))
.pause(253 milliseconds)
.exec(http("request_44")
    .get(uri8 + "/url/url/flamingo.jar")
    .headers(headers_42)
    .check(status.is(304)))
.pause(226 milliseconds) and so on...
```

Can anyone guide me, why is this happening???
Or is there any need to import gatling libraries to get this displayed in html reports??

Your help would be much appreciated.

thanks,
Praveen Mourya

Comment: Can you give the entire file?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee
Because of limitations, I can send modified code (not exactly). Please let me know in case if you need further more details on this.

[File link...](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=60FF78982229898A&resid=60FF78982229898A%2160038&authkey=AKvbbq3iqqLprhM)